# Import list of strings to tuples

Tags: python

Say if I have a text file containing a list of strings eg:

```
111 234324 john smith
123 123113 edward jones
131 423432 ben david
```

How could I import the strings from a text file and create a tuple for each line?

So they would read

```
(131, 234324, "john", "smith")
(123, 123113, "edward", "jones")
(131, 423432, "ben", "david")
```

and then print each tuple out line by line?

Thanks.

Comment: What part do you not know how to do? Open the file? Read lines? Find spaces? Create tuples? Create integers from strings? Print? Install Python? All of the above?

Comment: Reading the lines, create a tuple for each line and store them, so I can perform operations on different parts of each tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
result = None
with open('input.txt') as f:
    result = [tuple(line.split()) for line in f]

for t in result:
    print(t)
```

Comment: With that code the tuples are printed in one block as a list of tuples and not seperated with new lines. I am using python 3.1.4.

Comment: @user2975192 All right, there you go. But it's really not that hard to find it out for yourself...

Comment: Thanks alot. One more question, how can I store each tuple generated seperately so I can perform operations on each and manipulate the data.

Comment: @user2975192 Not sure what you're up to, but you're free to assign any of them to separate variables. Like: `x = result[0]`, `y = result[1]`. If you're sure that there will be always 3 of them you can do: `x,y,z = result` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
# open your_file    

for line in your_file:
    t = tuple(line.split())
    print t
```